# Testing interface at runtime without casting

Tags: typescript

I have code like this, where I need to handle objects with potentially different interfaces:

```
interface A { 
    a: any[];
}
interface B { 
    b: any[];
}

function doSomething(x: A | B) {
    if (x.a && x.a.length) console.log(x.a)
    if (x.b && x.b.length) console.log(x.b) 
}
```

and each instance of `x.a` and `x.a.length` results in a compile time error stating

> Property 'a' does not exist on type 'A | B'.
>   Property 'a' does not exist on type 'B'.

I know I could type cast every single instance where I test the interface of `x` (i.e. `if( (<A>x).a && (<A>x).a.length)` ) but with dozens of type / attribute combinations, this gets old in a hurry.

Is there a way of testing the interface of an object at runtime in typescript without casting every single test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isA(obj: A | B): obj is A {
    return (obj as A).a != undefined;
}

function isB(obj: A | B): obj is B {
    return (obj as B).b != undefined;
}

function doSomething(x: A | B) {
    if (isA(x)) console.log(x.a);
    if (isB(x)) console.log(x.b);
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20A%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20isA(obj%3A%20A%20%7C%20B)%3A%20obj%20is%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(obj%20as%20A).a%20!%3D%20undefined%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20isB(obj%3A%20A%20%7C%20B)%3A%20obj%20is%20B%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(obj%20as%20B).b%20!%3D%20undefined%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20doSomething(x%3A%20A%20%7C%20B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isA(x))%20console.log(x.a)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isB(x))%20console.log(x.b)%3B%0A%7D))

The compiler knows that if `isA(x)` fails then x is `B`, so this works as well:

```
function doSomething(x: A | B) {
    if (isA(x)) console.log(x.a);
    else console.log(x.b);
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20A%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20isA(obj%3A%20A%20%7C%20B)%3A%20obj%20is%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(obj%20as%20A).a%20!%3D%20undefined%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20isB(obj%3A%20A%20%7C%20B)%3A%20obj%20is%20B%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(obj%20as%20B).b%20!%3D%20undefined%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20doSomething(x%3A%20A%20%7C%20B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isA(x))%20console.log(x.a)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20else%20console.log(x.b)%3B%0A%7D))

Comment: Just thought of secret option C, which is to cast local variable like so: `var _x:B = <B>x; if( _x.a !== undefined){ /* do things with _x */}`, which is [about 12 times faster](https://jsperf.com/type-casting-v-type-guard) in the compiled code.